# Broken packages in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management

When I type sudo apt upgrade
I get this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic : Depends: linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried solutions on google but they aren't working.
I am new to this so please explain accordingly.
I am also not able to change brightness using keyboard.
Edit1:

I tried sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I tried apt list --upgradable

```
Listing... Done
dpkg-dev/focal-security,focal-security 1.19.7ubuntu3.2 all [upgradable from: 1.19.7ubuntu3]
dpkg/focal-security 1.19.7ubuntu3.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.19.7ubuntu3]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/focal-security 2.36.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.36.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0/focal-security 2.36.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.36.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
libdpkg-perl/focal-security,focal-security 1.19.7ubuntu3.2 all [upgradable from: 1.19.7ubuntu3]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/focal-security 2.36.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.36.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/focal-security 2.36.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.36.0-0ubuntu0.20.04.3]
orca/focal-security,focal-security 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 all [upgradable from: 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1]
```

sudo apt install linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/28.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 100 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic.
(Reading database ... 187741 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic_5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1_amd
64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic (5.13.0-40.45~20.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-5.13.0-40-gener
ic:
 linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic depends on linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic | linu
x-image-unsigned-5.13.0-40-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic is not installed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-40-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic (5.13.0-44.49
~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote s
ubstitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic (5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote s
ubstitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic package post-installation script subpro
cess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic
 linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic
 linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

df -h;df -i

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6   46G   39G  5.0G  89% /
tmpfs           7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   33M  224M  13% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15904
/dev/loop1      228M  228M     0 100% /snap/code/96
/dev/loop3       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop4      111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12834
/dev/loop5      220M  220M     0 100% /snap/code/97
/dev/loop6       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15534
/dev/loop7       82M   82M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop8       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1434
/dev/loop9      112M  112M     0 100% /snap/core/13250
/dev/loop10      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop11      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/125
/dev/loop12     249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
tmpfs           1.6G   60K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           1964052    637 1963415    1% /dev
tmpfs          1972933   1176 1971757    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6 3055616 400215 2655401   14% /
tmpfs          1972933      1 1972932    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1972933      5 1972928    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1972933     19 1972914    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1       0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop0          29     29       0  100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2         484    484       0  100% /snap/snapd/15904
/dev/loop1        3914   3914       0  100% /snap/code/96
/dev/loop3       11789  11789       0  100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop4       12847  12847       0  100% /snap/core/12834
/dev/loop5        3914   3914       0  100% /snap/code/97
/dev/loop6         484    484       0  100% /snap/snapd/15534
/dev/loop7       76177  76177       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop8       11789  11789       0  100% /snap/core20/1434
/dev/loop9       12848  12848       0  100% /snap/core/13250
/dev/loop10      65095  65095       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop11      17311  17311       0  100% /snap/snap-store/558
tmpfs          1972933     45 1972888    1% /run/user/125
/dev/loop12      17495  17495       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
tmpfs          1972933    104 1972829    1% /run/user/1000
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic:
 linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic depends on linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-40-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic is not installed.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-40-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic (5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-41-generic (5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.13.0-44-generic (5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic
```

Comment: you need to have the system fully updated before you do an upgrade,have you done this?

Comment: Can you run `sudo apt update` and try again?

Comment: I did that, 
I got this:

Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: please can you show `sudo apt install linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic` and `df -h;df -i`

Comment: your /etc/default/grub file is brocken.  `sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak.  and now we copying the default. `sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub` then `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @nobody I tried the first command 
sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak.

mv: cannot stat '/etc/default/grub': No such file or directory

Comment: the file has to be there `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution` At least your error message tell's that.

Comment: @nobody So what command should I use?
I am not able to find it

Comment: okay `sudo cp -v /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub`

Comment: @nobody Its working now. 
It gave output: `'/usr/share/grub/default/grub' -> '/etc/default/grub'`
Next?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: I still got an error which I edited have edited in post now

Answer (score 0):

Two differned causes. Your /etc/default/grub was longer brocken. and your /boot is now full.
[free space in /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)